# How to Roll up multiple rows into a single row and column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, command, row

I got the table as below:

```
| Ent | Loc | Pdate     | Sdate     | Ent1 | Loc1 | No  | 
----------------------------------------------------------
| 01  | A   | 2-sep-18  | 20-sep-18 | A1   | B    | S01 |
| 01  | A   | 1-sep-18  | 20-sep-18 | A1   | B    | S02 |
| 01  | A   | 3-sep-18  | 20-sep-18 | A1   | C    | S02 |
| 01  | A   | 1-sep-18  | 20-sep-18 | A1   | C    | S02 |
| 01  | A   | 1-sep-18  | 20-sep-18 | A1   | D    | S02 |
| 01  | A   | 3-sep-18  | 20-sep-18 | A1   | D    | S02 |
```

and this is the result I want:

```
| Ent | Loc | Pdate     | Sdate     | Ent1 | Loc1 | No      | 
-------------------------------------------------------------
| 01  | A   | 2-sep-18  | 20-sep-18 | A1   | B    | S01,S02 |
| 01  | A   | 1-sep-18  | 20-sep-18 | A1   | B    | S01,S02 |
| 01  | A   | 3-sep-18  | 20-sep-18 | A1   | C    | S02     |
| 01  | A   | 1-sep-18  | 20-sep-18 | A1   | C    | S02     |
| 01  | A   | 1-sep-18  | 20-sep-18 | A1   | D    | S02     |
| 01  | A   | 3-sep-18  | 20-sep-18 | A1   | D    | S02     |
```

I think it might use for an XML command but I'm unsure how.

Comment: I've inlined the image. Please [edit] the post and replace the image by the text instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear, however you can use a couple of CTEs to prepare your data and then `STRING_AGG` (starting from SQL Server 2017) to concatenate the values:

```
declare @tmp table( 
    Ent    varchar(2), 
    Loc    varchar(1),
    Pdate  date,      
    Sdate  date, 
    Ent1   varchar(2), 
    Loc1   varchar(1), 
    No     varchar(max)
) 

insert into @tmp values
 ('01', 'A', '2018-09-02', '2018-09-20', 'A1', 'B', 'S01')
,('01', 'A', '2018-09-01', '2018-09-20', 'A1', 'B', 'S02')
,('01', 'A', '2018-09-03', '2018-09-20', 'A1', 'C', 'S02')
,('01', 'A', '2018-09-01', '2018-09-20', 'A1', 'C', 'S02')
,('01', 'A', '2018-09-01', '2018-09-20', 'A1', 'D', 'S02')
,('01', 'A', '2018-09-03', '2018-09-20', 'A1', 'D', 'S02')

;with 
 A as(
    select ent, loc, ent1, loc1, no
    from @tmp
    group by ent, loc, ent1, loc1, no
    )
,B as(
    select ent, loc, ent1, loc1, STRING_AGG(No, ',') as No 
    from A
    group by ent, loc, ent1, loc1
    )
select T.Ent, T.Loc, T.Pdate, T.Sdate, T.Ent1, T.Loc1, B.No 
from @tmp T
inner join B 
    on T.Ent = B.Ent and T.Loc = B.Loc and T.Ent1 = B.Ent1 and T.Loc1 = B.Loc1
```

Result:

[image]

If you are using SQL Server < 2017 you will not be able to use `STRING_AGG` and you qill have to write your own string aggregation logic.